# Narrow map value type from an as const object

Tags: typescript

I currently have the following object:

```
const LOGIC_CATEGORIES = {
  core: "Core",
  transformer: "Transformers",
  logic: "Logical Operators",
  requests: "Requests",
} as const
```

Now I use it as follows:

```
Object.keys(LOGIC_CATEGORIES).map((category) => (...))
```

The problem is that here `category` is now a string instead of possible values for a key from the `LOGIC_CATEGORIES` object. How would I go about narrowing down this return value?

An option is to make the types broader, but then you lose type safety.

Comment: I did not realise that it was related to the `Object.keys()` functionality, thank you for the quick reply.